# Why when I start thin server in production mode it can't find my users table, but it does in regular mode ? - Rails 3

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

I am trying to replicate an error in my app in production, but when I launch thin like this:

`thin -e production start`

When I go to my main page I get this:

```
ActiveRecord::StatementInvalid in Devise::SessionsController#new

Could not find table 'users'
```

Which is strange because once I do:

`thin start`

That page now works.

Do I have to run a new set of migrations now that I am in production mode ? Or is it that in production mode it doesn't like SQLite ?

Thanks.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Assuming config/database.yml is setup correctly, and that you have not setup your production database, you will need to:

```
rake db:setup RAILS_ENV="production"
```

to setup your production database.  This method looks at the schema file instead of applying all your migrations which is the preferred method.

I hope this helps.

Comment: One last thing, when I try to execute `rails c RAILS_ENV=production` I get this error: `/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p0/gems/activerecord-3.0.6/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_specification.rb:62:in 'establish_connection': RAILS_ENV=production database is not configured (ActiveRecord::AdapterNotSpecified)`

What could be causing this ?